# MKMapCamera showing south

Tags: swift2, mapkit, ios9, mkmapcamera

is there a way to load mapKit facing south instead of north in swift 2?

I have tried MKMapCamera and looked at apple documentation but nothing I have read or tried is working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The following Swift code creates an [`MKMapCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapCamera_class/) object with a heading of 180°, which orients the map to face South:

```
let camera = MKMapCamera()
camera.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858, longitude: 2.294)
camera.heading = 180.0
mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
```

The `heading` property of an `MKMapCamera` controls the compass angle the map will face. 0° is North, 45° is North East, 90° is East, and so on.

If you have a view controller with an IB outlet to an [`MKMapView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView) object, you can add the above code to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let camera = MKMapCamera()
    camera.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.858, longitude: 2.294)
    camera.heading = 180.0
    mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
}
```